# java.io.IOException: Timed out waiting for Mini HDFS Cluster to start

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I am getting timeout exception while trying to start the Hbase mini cluster. Further I want to write a hbase test case but currently its failing for hadoop 3.1.1 and hbase 2.0.2 combination.

1) Have tried with all the version of > = 3.1.1 and hbase >=2.0.0 
2) Have taken code from https://github.com/apache/hbase/blob/rel/2.0.2/hbase-server/src/test/java/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/TestHBaseTestingUtility.java
and 
https://github.com/apache/ranger/blob/master/hbase-agent/src/test/java/org/apache/ranger/authorization/hbase/HBaseRangerAuthorizationTest.java

````
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseTestingUtility;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HConstants;
public class HBaseRangerAuthorizationTest2 {

        private static int port;
        private static HBaseTestingUtility utility;
        public static void main(String args[]) {
            try {
                port = getFreePort();     
                utility = new HBaseTestingUtility();
                utility.getConfiguration().set("test.hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort", "" + port);
                utility.getConfiguration().set("hbase.master.port", "" + getFreePort());
                utility.getConfiguration().set("hbase.master.info.port", "" + getFreePort());
                utility.getConfiguration().set("hbase.regionserver.port", "" + getFreePort());
                utility.getConfiguration().set("hbase.regionserver.info.port", "" + getFreePort());
                utility.getConfiguration().set("zookeeper.znode.parent", "/hbase-unsecure");
                utility.startMiniCluster();

                /*
                utility= new HBaseTestingUtility();
                // Set a different zk path for each cluster
                utility.getConfiguration().set(HConstants.ZOOKEEPER_ZNODE_PARENT, "/1");
                utility.startMiniZKCluster();
                utility.startMiniCluster();*/
            }catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        public static int getFreePort() throws IOException {
            ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(0);
            int port = serverSocket.getLocalPort();
            serverSocket.close();
            return port;
        }
}```

I expect the mini server should start without fail.
````

Answer (score 0):

I am using hadoop version 2.7.3 and hbase version 1.1.2

For timeout exception, add the hadoop-client dependency to your gradle file:

```
compile 'org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-client:2.7.3'
```

Further check if you have added the dependency:

```
compile 'org.apache.hbase:hbase-testing-util:1.1.2'
```